# Pros & Cons of Using animateToRegion() vs animateCamera()

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-native-maps

Building out react-native-maps and trying to decide the pros and cons of using animateToRegion vs. animateCamera. In the past we've handled everything on a region basis.

Seems like region would be a better choice, as you won't have to worry about differences between elevation and zoom, while also having a more granular control of the exact region being displayed if needed.

Anyone have any thoughts or experiences that have led them to one or the other?

Answer (score 5):

I just made this switch myself. I found that `animateCamera()` is more versatile and allows for cleaner syntax.

The biggest pro for `animateCamera()` is that you can do multiple animations from a single method call.

An example of centering to coords and turning the camera 180 degrees with `animateCamera()`:

```
this.map.animateCamera({
  center: {
    latitude: 0,
    longitude: 0,
  },
  heading: 180,
});
```

If you wanted to do the same thing with `animateToRegion()` you would need to call **two** methods:

```
this.map.animateToRegion({
  latitude: 0,
  longitude: 0,
});
this.map.animateCamera({
  heading: 180,
});
```

Not as clean.

As of right now, a con for `animateCamera()` is that you don't seem to be able to pass a `latitudeDelta` and `longitudeDelta` into the `center` property like you can with region, specified [here](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/mapview.md#types).

In short, if you don't need to use a `latitudeDelta` and `longitudeDelta` then `animateCamera()` is the way to go. If I had to speculate, I would say `animateToRegion()` is going to be deprecated like the other methods sometime in the future in favor of `animateCamera()`.